# ReactJS and Redux - Correct creation of the connect class component with types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I've started to learn React + Redux.

I got the following reducer:

```
/**
 * Import custom types.
 */
import { User } from "../types/user.type";
import { Action } from "../types/reducers/profileReducer.type";

/**
 * Creates profile reducer to set and retrieve currently logged in user.
 * @param user - User object, indicating the current state.
 * @param action - Action object, which will indicate which action to apply.
 * @returns User object after the action applied.
 */
const profileReducer = (user: User | null = null, action: Action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_PROFILE': // Set users profile
      return user = action.payload ? action.payload.user : null;
    default: // Let's set the default action to retrieve the users profile
      return user;
  }
};

/**
 * Export default reducer.
 */
export default profileReducer;
```

And following action -

```
/**
 * Import custom types.
 */
import { User } from '../types/user.type';
import { Action } from '../types/reducers/profileReducer.type';

/**
 * Returns an action for setting a profile.
 * @param user - User object which should be set as current users profile.
 * @returns Action for setting a new users profile object.
 */
export const setProfile = (user: User): Action => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_PROFILE',
    payload: {
      user 
    }
  };
}

/**
 * Export all profile actions.
 */
export default {
  setProfile
}
```

Finally, these are the types -

profileReducer:

```
/**
 * Import custom types.
 */
import { User } from "../user.type";

export interface Action {
  type: ActionType; // Type of the action
  payload?: {
    user: User; // User object which will be set upon 'SET_PROFILE' action
  }
};

export type ActionType = 'SET_PROFILE';
```

User:

```
export interface User {
  id: string; // ID of the user
  name: string; // Name of the user
  lastName: string; // Last name of the user
  email: string; // Email of the user
  admin: boolean; // Boolean indicator if the user is admin
  active: boolean; // Boolean indicator if the user is active
  gender: boolean; // Gender of the user
  createdAt: string; // Date object when the user was created
  updatedAt: string; // Date object when the user was updated
  birthDate: number; // Date when user was born
  birthYear: number; // Year when user was born
  birthMonth: number; // Month when user was born
}
```

Now I have the following class component -

```
/**
 * Import React libraries.
 */
import React, { Dispatch } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Import third-party libraries.
 */
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

/**
 * Import custom reducer actions.
 */
import actions from '../../actions';

/**
 * Import custom types.
 */
import { HeaderProps } from '../../types/header.type';
import { User } from '../../types/user.type';
import { Action } from '../../types/reducers/profileReducer.type';

/**
 * Import custom scss.
 */
import './Header.scss';

/**
 * Creates Header component class.
 */
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component<HeaderProps> {
  /**
   * Renders Header component view.
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col md="12">
          { !this.state.isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/" /> }
          <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" className="app-header">

          { /* Style for medium and larger devices */ }
          <div className="d-none d-md-block text-right w-100">
            <Link to="/profile" className="text-dark">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user" className="mr-2" />
              { this.props.profile && `${this.props.profile.name} ${this.props.profile.lastName}` }
            </Link>
          </div>
          </Navbar>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}

/**
 * Creates profile state and sets as parameters for the header component.
 * @param state - Redux store state object.
 */
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({ profile: state.profile });

/**
 * Creates a dispatch mapping, which will be passed in to properties.
 * @param dispatch - Dispatch parameter which takes in a specific action.
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => ({
  setProfile: (user: User) => dispatch(actions.profile.setProfile(user))
});

/**
 * Export default header component.
 */
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HeaderComponent);
```

And HeaderProps is as following:

```
export interface HeaderProps {
  profile?: User; // Currently logged in users profile
  setProfile?: Function; // Dispatch function on redux.
}
```

Currently several questions arises:

1) If I remove optional sign (?) from the HeaderProps properties, reactJs app won't compile anymore and complain about missing properties in the parent component in which I call Header component. This is due to the fact that I don't pass any property when calling `<Header />`, that is, I'm just calling `<Header />` instead of `<Header setProfile={..} profile={} />`, because obviously - we are retrieving them from the connect function, right? How to fix that?

2) What types should I use for the state? Where I currently have `state: any`? I can't seem to figure that out.

3) Have I used the types for the mapDispatchToProps function correctly? If no, what would you change?

4) Have I defined the type for the Component correctly? I can't access the default react functions, like setState, e.t.c. should I define them myself in HeaderProps type?

5) Do you see any issues on the way how I have used the redux? In the tutorial they have separated them in two separate files - one which holds Header implementation, and the second one which holds redux connection to Header. Is the way I'm doing that OK?